# Eclipselink does not detect a dirty entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I was experimenting with eclipselink. I am trying to update an existing entity in database. The JPA entity only has public fields and fields are annotated with JPA annotation. The code loads an entity using `EntityManager.find()`.

The code creates an instance of JPA entity, assigns value to public fields of the entity and invokes EntityManager.merge(entity) method. Eclipselink does not update database record. I enabled log to see whether Eclipselink issues SQL statement or not.

Eclipselink does not issue any update statement. Does this mean that even if I use field persistence, I can not assign value to public fields of the entity instead of using setter method?

Thanks,
Chir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weaving introduces some optimizations such as lazy onetoone and manytones and change tracking.  The only way these can work is if you use the accessor method on the entity, but if that isn't an option, you can turn them off as needed.  See 
http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_changetracking.htm
For details on change tracking.

Comment: Thanks Chris, If JPA is used in JavaSE environment, it detects change made to public or private fields of the entity and updates database. But the same does not work in JavaEE environment.

Comment: Weaving is integrated with the container, while in javaSE it requires hooking in an agent at start up.  No weaving means it must use deferred change detection, which creates backups for comparisons.  While weaving defaults to attribute change tracking, requiring apps to use the accessors to be able to register for changes.  If you can't use accessors, you'll need to specify a different change detection strategy.  Please note the JPA spec really only allows using accessors to get at entities externally, so some other features like lazy loading of basics might not work either.